# ActiveRecord: Scope for where attribute is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to grab those `Blogs` where its `title.present? == true`. (`Blogs` have a string attribute of `title`).

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_present_titles, -> {where("#{title.present?} == ?", true)} #doesn't work
end

@blogs = Blog.with_present_titles #doesn't work
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Your database column is `title` isn't it?  Your scope definition should probably be `{ where("title is not null and title != ''") }` which returns all blogs with non empty and not null title.

Comment: @vee works!  Please post an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return all records with some values in `title` column, you would update your scope with the following query:

```
scope :with_present_titles, -> { where("title is not null and title != ''") }
```

This returns all records with some value in title column leaving any `null` and empty titles.

`.present?` being a method provided by rails, you cannot simply use these methods in your DB queries.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your rails version you can also use `where.not` (introduced in rails 4) E.g.

```
scope :with_present_titles, ->{where.not(title: [nil,'']) }
#Blog.with_present_titles.to_sql
#=> "SELECT [blogs].* 
#    FROM [blogs] 
#    WHERE (NOT (([blogs].[title] = '' OR [blogs].[title] IS NULL)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the following scope.

```
scope :with_present_titles, -> { where('title IS NOT ? AND TITLE != ?', nil, '') }
```